# ¿Cómo acceder al valor de un SPAN en Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Tengo el siguiente etiquetado en html

```
<label class="checkbox">
      <span class="pull-right" style="padding-bottom: 16px;">
         <a data-toggle="modal" href="#">Conexión IP <span id="ipId"></span></a>
      </span>
</label>
```

pero quiero acceder al valor de el span con el id `ipId` desde typecript, pero no funciona:

```
let unit : string = (<HTMLSpanElement>document.getElementById("ipId")).value;
```

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta?

Comment: Y porque no creas un input hidden pones el valor de la ip en su propiedad value y obtienes el value del input.

Comment: La ip debe ser visible al cliente

Comment: No te digo que quites el span y pongas el input puede tener ambos el input type hidden jamas se vera y ambos tendran el mismo valor siempre, se me ocure esto porque talvez es más fácil acceder al value de un input que al value de un span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si entendí bien, puedes probar con lo siguiente:

**Vista**

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <span class="pull-right" style="padding-bottom: 16px;">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#">Conexión IP <span id="ipId">{{ipPrueba}}</span></a>
  </span>
</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="evaluar()">Evaluar</button>
```

**Typescript**

```
ipPrueba: string = '192.168.1.133';
evaluar()
{
  //Declaracion de la variable a utilizar
  let unit : string = document.getElementById('ipId').innerHTML;
  //Verificamos por consola el valor obtenido
  console.log("Unit: ", unit)
  //Evaluamos si el valor es indefinido, si no, es un valor valido
  if (unit == undefined)
  {
    console.log("undefined")
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("Valid!")
  }
}
```

**Resultado**

`Script:  192.168.1.133 Valid!`

Si de pronto no es lo que esperas, me haces saber!

Comment: Lo que retorna es undefined, lo que yo busco es obtener el valor que tiene ese span. el valor de ese span se lo asigno mediante una llamada AJAX por JavaScript

Comment: @r0b0f0sn0w obtienes un valor indefinido porque no tienes valor alguno asignado a ese span. Actualice la respuesta para que veas como lo hago!

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude obtener el valor de el span. : ) PD: Soy nuevo en angular y typescript.

Comment: @r0b0f0sn0w que bueno que te haya ayudado, es con gusto!

Comment: Hola @r0b0f0sn0w No te sirvió mi respuesta?

Comment: Si solo que me equivoque de respuesta al señalar la correcta.

Comment: Te podría contactar de algún modo para algunas dudas que tengo sobre angular?

Answer (score 0):

Con Angular puedes poner tag en los elementos del DOM usando `#someTag`, luego con `@ViewChild('someTag')` obtienes el elemento.

**HTML:**

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <span class="pull-right" style="padding-bottom: 16px;">
     <a data-toggle="modal" href="#">Conexión IP <span #ipId id="ipId"></span></a>
  </span>
</label>
```

---

**Código:**

```
import {AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('ipId') span: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // Apartir de aqui lo tienes disponible
        console.log(this.span.nativeElement); // Etiqueta Span
        console.log(this.span.nativeElement.innerHTML); // El valor de la etiqueta
    }
}
```

Comment: Si funciona, pero me devuelve la etiqueta, yo lo que quiero obtener es lo que contiene ese span, en mi caso tengo una ip asignada, quiero obtener la IP. Que se asignó.

Comment: Una vez que obtienes la etiqueta puedes obtener su valor, solo tienes que poner `.innerHTML;`.